# How to get value form nested object in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some code on nodejs using mongoose module, and I need to get nested value, let I show you:

I create Schema

```
var clientScheme = mongoose.Schema({
    name: Object
    address: String,
    number: Number,
    operator: Object,
    services: Object,
    email: String
})
```

Then I create model:

```
var Client = mongoose.model('Client', clientScheme);
```

Then goes creating/saving - it's easy, I just show you first client.json

```
   {
        "name":{
             "first":"John",
             "last":"Smith"
              },
        "address":"Avenue 1",
        "number": 7012341,
        "email":"john@gmail.com"
    }
```

And then, I need to get this client by first name. I try to:

```
clients.find({"name":{"first":"John"}})
```

Doesn't work.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with  :

```
db.clients.find({"name.first":"John"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use dotted notation:

```
Client.find({"name.first": "John"}, function(err, clients){
    // your callback body here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you try to find a record which has 'name' exactly like this:

```
{first: "John"}
```

but your client has name: {first: "John", last: "Smith"}

So, any of the following queries will find your client:

```
clients.find({"name.first": "John"}) or
clients.find({"name.last": "Smith"}) or
clients.find({"name": {first: "John", last: "Smith"}})
```

Hope it helps.