# Mongoose How to get a nested object within a document via findOne

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to get a nested object within a certain document (searched by user ID) that also has an object inside of it (there's no guarantee that this object will be the same object).

I have the User model to be:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { bool } = require('@hapi/joi');

const monitoringSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: Object,
    default: {}
})

const hubSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    hubID: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    isSetup: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    monitoring: {
        type: monitoringSchema
    }
}, {strict:false})

const finalUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 255
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 255,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 10,
        max: 1024,
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    isVerified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    hub: {
        type: hubSchema
    }
},  {strict:false});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', finalUserSchema);
```

OR It has the layout:

```
_id: "id"
isVerified: true
username: "nathan"
email: "email@email.com"
hub:
    hubID: "id"
    monitoring: // WHOLE OBJECT I NEED TO RETREIVE
        exampleObject: 
            exampleValue: exampleKey
```

I have an array of user IDs I need to update and I tried the query:

```
for(i in usersToUpdate){
        User.findOne({_id: usersToUpdate[i], "hub.monitoring": {}}, {}, callbackResponse);
        function callbackResponse(err, data){
            if(err) return console.log(err)
            console.log(data)
        }
    }
```

But it returns `null` as the data so obviously the query is wrong. I know the error is:

```
{_id: usersToUpdate[i], "hub.monitoring": {}}
```

more specifically:

```
"hub.monitoring": {}
```

I'm using `{}` to reference an object within monitoring, what's the correct reference to reference an unknown object and get it's values back, like a wildcard? I've tried:

```
 {_id: usersToUpdate[i], "hub.monitoring": Object}
```

and it still doesn't work. I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33253717/12647189), however they reference a value that they already know, like a name?

Comment: Try using `"hub.monitoring": {$exists: true}`.

Comment: If the `hubID` is known you can just match on that `"hub.hubID" : <hubID>`, and then extract the `monitoring` object from result in javascript.

Comment: @ShridharSharma It works, but that still returns the WHOLE document, I just want the `monitoring` object from the document returned.....

Comment: @ambianBeing I will not know the `hubID` unless I do multiple queries, I want to avoid that as this whole code will be run on every user I have in my db every day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve only the `monitoring` object, `aggregation` pipeline can be used.

Using [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter and [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to output/ supress fields.

```
User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(usersToUpdate[i]),
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      monitoring: "$hub.monitoring",
      _id: 0,
    },
  },
]).exec(callbackResponse);
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NF-1Im_WPxz)

Comment: That does work, however it returns all other objects within the `monitoring` object as `[Object]` and not their actual values?

Comment: @Nathan You should be getting plain javascript object with values since mongoose doesn't cast aggregation pipelines. Also have updated the answer to explicitly cast id as ObjectId if they are coming as strings (mongoose would not cast them because of aggregation). Try it out. Also a sample document of monitoring would help in reproducing it, please show that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the 2 object form of findOne where the first object is the query and the second object is the projection of what you want to return.

```
User.findOne({_id: usersToUpdate[i]}, {"hub.monitoring": {$exists: true}}, callbackResponse);
function callbackResponse(err, data){
    if(err) return console.log(err)
    console.log(data)
}
```

This way, the object will be returned if the monitoring object exist.

Comment: Someone has commented that answer and I replied that it still returns the WHOLE document involved, not the singular `monitoring` object....

Comment: The comment placed `hub.monitoring` as a query parameter. Placing it in the second object tells you which fields of the document to return.